# map is not a function after axios delete request

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, request

When I use map function for the following code, after deleting an user, I get an error: map is not a function.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useAxiosFunction from "../../hooks/useAxiosFunction";
import axios from 'axios'

const UsersList = () => {

    const [users, error, loading, axiosFetch] = useAxiosFunction();

    const getData = () => {
        axiosFetch({
            axiosInstance: axios,
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:3500/users'
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        axiosFetch({
            axiosInstance: axios,
            method: 'delete',
            url: 'http://localhost:3500/users',
            requestConfig: {
                data: {
                    id: id
                }
            }
        });
    }

    const content = (
        <div>
            <h1> USERS LIST </h1>
            {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}

            {!loading && error && <p className="errMsg">{error}</p>}

            {!loading && !error && users?.length &&
                <ul>
                    { users.map((user, i) => (<li key={user._id}>{`${user.username}`}<button onClick={() => handleDelete(user._id)}>BUTTON</button></li>)) }
                </ul>
            }

            {!loading && !error && !users?.length && users?.data &&
                <p>{`userId: ${users.data?.userId}, title: ${users.data?.title}, body: ${users.data?.body}`}</p>}

            {!loading && !error && !users && <p>No users to display</p>}

        </div>
    )

    return content
}
export default UsersList
```

my useAxiosFunction.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useAxiosFunction = () => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [controller, setController] = useState();

    const axiosFetch = async (configObj) => {
        const {
            axiosInstance,
            method,
            url,
            requestConfig = {}
        } = configObj;

        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const ctrl = new AbortController();
            setController(ctrl);
            const res = await axiosInstance[method.toLowerCase()](url, {
                ...requestConfig,
                signal: ctrl.signal
            });
            console.log(res);
            setResponse(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            setError(err.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(controller)

        // useEffect cleanup function
        return () => controller && controller.abort();

    }, [controller]);

    return [response, error, loading, axiosFetch];
}

export default useAxiosFunction
```

I've added:
`{ Array.isArray(users) && users?.map((user, i) => (<li key={user._id}>{`${user.username}`}<button onClick={() => handleDelete(user._id)}>BUTTON</button></li>)) }`
to check if users is array and it's not rendering until getData() is called again.

I can't understand why it map function works after refresh but not after deleting an user.

Comment: It wont work if your `delete` api does not return all remaning users.

Comment: Not sure your Axios hook is the best idea. There's a reason why react-query separates queries and mutations